# What's the modern equivalent of GetKeys() in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard

I'm looking to read the state of the keyboard in Cocoa (for a game I'm building in SpriteKit).

NSResponder will certainly give me key presses, but I don't get events for modifier presses, and if I hold down a single key, and then press another key, I stop getting keyDown events for the first.

In ancient times (on my MacPlus), I used `GetKeys()` to fetch the keyboard state at the top of each frame. 
I'm surprised and baffled that this *still* seems to work:

```
KeyMap keys; 
GetKeys(keys); 
UInt32 keys3 = CFSwapIn32BigToHost(keys[3].bigEndianValue); 
if (keys3 & 4) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"F1 is down"); 
}
```

However, I'm certain that there must be issues with localization, different keyboards, or something (using a 30-year old toolbox call gives me pause).

Is there a modern equivalent to this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this, centering around the `NSEvent` API.

1. You could ask the `NSApplication` instance for the `currentEvent`. This will give you an `NSEvent`, and you could inspect its `characters`, `charactersIgnoringModifiers`, `modifierFlags`, etc.
2. If you're only interested in modifiers, you could just ask for the `+[NSEvent modifierFlags]` to return to you a bit mask of the currently pressed modifier keys.
3. You could install an event monitor (either global or local) to notify when you keys and/or modifiers change.

The last approach is probably the best one, because it doesn't require polling.

Comment: Another way (not saying it's better) is with Quartz calls, like `CGEventSourceKeyState( kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kVK_LeftArrow )`.

Comment: I don't think (1) works: if the `currentEvent` doesn't happen to be a key-up/down event, then `characters` [will raise an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534183-characters).